# how to calculate css custom variables? calc(percentage * percentage)

Tags: html, css, variables, calc, hsl

I tried to calculate some `css variables`. But I've a problem with `calc(percentage * percentage)`.
It seem a problem with percentage multiplied by percentage.

```
  --test: 30%;
  --test2: 50%;
  background: hsl(
    10deg,
    40%,
    calc( 50% * var(--test) / var(test2) ) // doesn't work
  );

background: hsl(
    10deg,
    40%,
    calc( 50% * 1 ) // works
  );

  background: hsl(
    10deg,
    40%,
    calc( 50% * 100% ) // doesn't work
  );

  background: hsl(
    10deg,
    40%,
    calc( 50% * (100% / 100%) ) // doesn't work too
  );
```

Anyone can solve the problem with mixed unit? I cannot avoid using % in my css var.

Comment: and what (percentage * percentage) should give as a result? this is an invalid operation

Comment: the background color wouldn't be set. the hsl() function didn't recognize the % * %

Comment: because you cannot mutiply % with %, it's invalid so the whole calc is invalid (you cannot also divide with %)

Comment: how i do calculation with variables containing with % unit?

Comment: you simply cannot, you need to rethink your logic ... % * % is simply invalid. Any mix of unit is simply invalid. If I told you % * px, what should be the result? it's invalid ...

Comment: but 100vw - 20px is valid, why % - % is not?

Comment: because this is not a multiplicate and `% - %` is valid. What is not valid is `% * %` (read the duplicate to understand the rules)

Comment: so is this invalid too? calc(100vw * (20px / 40px))

Comment: read the duplicate please